Debugger issues with Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition with SSIS Extension
Having an issue debugging in Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition with SSIS SQL Server Integration Services installed.
A Script Task (VB code) runs without issue. However, after placing a BREAKPOINT on a line of code in said script, then Start the package, the debugger launches another instance of VS2022 (this is normal) to show the source code in debug mode.
The issue is that the debugger's expectation as to the temporary location of the VB Source Code file is NOT where VS2022 actually placed it.
The debugger then prompts the user, asking for an assist in locating the .VB file.  That prompt shows where it THOUGHT the script-file would reside:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Vsta\ef2e0ba84b564a8884cd4098d7e48104\ScriptMain.vb
However, I located the file at:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Vsta\SSIS_ST160\Vsta3ViAcZp9lkW1vVjZI__tx0A\VstaKh3EjtKdjUWrjUXcQFo2Cg\ScriptMain.vb
When I chose this location, the debugger resumes as expected and all is well.
What's causing this odd behavior?!
HOW I'VE TRIED TO CORRECT THIS ISSUE:
I have tried exiting VS, clearing out the \Local\Temp\ subdirs, and watching VS create copies of scripts in the aforementioned path .. under "\SSIS_ST160\" .. which is NOT where the debugger thinks they shall reside.
I have also ensured the latest versions of VS and SSIS Extension are up-to-date, to no avail.
Note that VS2002 debugs in x64 mode .. with no option to change to x32 mode. Regardless, the machine it's running on is x64.
Has anyone seen this same behavior and, if so, how to resolve it?

The following may be of interest: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home

Hi, it looks like that VS debugger looks for source code files from other folders. Please check Debug Source Files page form your solution Properties.

It seems like that visual studio debugger looks for source code files from other folders. For this issue, here are suggestions you can check to troubleshoot:
1.Please check Debug Source Files property, this property page specifies where the debugger will look for source files when debugging the solution.
Right-click on your Solution in Solution Explorer and select Properties from the shortcut menu. Expand the Common Properties folder, and click the Debug Source Files page.
If this directory Temp\2\Vsta\ef2e0ba84b564a8884cd4098d7e48104\ exists, please remove it. Add try to add "\SSIS_ST160\"  to the Debug source Files.
2.The debugger uses symbol files to map the executable code back to the source code. If these symbol files reference ef2e0ba84b564a8884cd4098d7e48104 locations, the debugger will look there. Please check your symbol Files and try to empty Symbol Cache.
3.Try to clean and rebuild your project and reload it.
It seems like that your project is related to  SSIS SQL Server Integration Services, if the suggestions above don't help, please share snip code to help us better understand your scenario.

Thank you for the verbose feedback.
Unfortunately, none of the suggestions remedied my issue.


Debug Source Files
There was nothing listed in this section.  I tried adding 2 paths .. one of which included SSIS_ST160, to no avail.


Offered no change in the odd debugging issue.


Yes, of course. Unfortunately, the issue persists.


It's as if the SSIS Extension isn't properly communicating to VS2022 the location of temp VB source files, in active debug mode. It's placing the source files in a subdir of the location it IS looking. Bizarre...

Hi @PaulieD, are you using this extension?

Hello @dou-xu-msft.  I am using Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition. When I click on the Extensions menu, then Installed, these two are listed: (1) SQL Server Data Tools - SQL Editor. (2) SQL Server Integration Services Projects 2022 - Version 1.4 Release Date 2024-Apr-28 with note "Tested against Visual Studio 2022 17.9".
The title and version numbers are different from the link you provided. I installed these directly inside VS2022 via the Extensions area.
